# Foreign key on replicated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

I don't know much about replication.  I have some tables that are duplicated within several databases such as States, Postal Codes, etc.  Some tables do change data occasionally.  Can I make one database to hold all the tables and replicate them to other databases?  Or is replicating a database an all or nothing deal.  If I can replicate to other databases, can I create foreign key from that table?

Thank you

Comment: This is far too broad as it stands, and probably better off asked on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), however, the question is totally dependent on your RDBMS. You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server here, which are very different products. I suggest expanding your question  and tagging the correct RDBMS, and only the correct RDBMS.

Comment: If you use sql-server, based on the nature of your tables (States, Postal Codes...) that seems to be kind of static, with not too much changes, you could create a trigger in those tables, and then replicate the changes in the other databases (other sql server or other vendors) creating linked servers with these other databases. If your data changes often, you likely want to study another different alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I mistyped for mysql.  I'm using sql server 2016.  I'd still like to know if you can replicate specified tables into a database that's not a full replicated database.  I'd rather not have to write triggers.  And also, if you can replicate a single table, can it be used in relationships.  Thanks again.